# XAML C# Pivot Control LayoutCycleException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I do not know how to repair LayoutCycleException.

There are no hints on what's wrong.

I have a pivot control with five tabs and like 10 items per tab.
Initial tabbing thru works but when going back it hits this exception w/o any other information.

What to do?

**EDIT:**

Listing below is the content of the usercontrol. All sources are observable collection properties. To avoid null's, all collections are initialized on control creation:

```
    <Grid>
    <Pivot>
        <PivotItem x:Uid="Pivot-New">
            <GridView 
                ItemsSource="{Binding NewChassis, Mode=OneWay}" 
                SelectionMode="Single" 
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            />
        </PivotItem>

        <PivotItem x:Uid="Pivot-Errors">
            <GridView 
                ItemsSource="{Binding ErrorEvents, Mode=OneWay}" 
                SelectionMode="Single" 
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            />
        </PivotItem>

        <PivotItem x:Uid="Pivot-Warnings">
            <GridView 
                ItemsSource="{Binding WarningEvents, Mode=OneWay}" 
                SelectionMode="Single" 
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            />
        </PivotItem>

        <PivotItem x:Uid="Pivot-Unassigned">
            <GridView 
                ItemsSource="{Binding UnassignedEvents, Mode=OneWay}" 
                SelectionMode="Single" 
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            />
        </PivotItem>

        <PivotItem x:Uid="Pivot-Starts">
            <GridView 
                ItemsSource="{Binding StartEvents, Mode=OneWay}" 
                SelectionMode="Single" 
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            />
        </PivotItem>

        <PivotItem x:Uid="Pivot-Ends">
            <GridView 
                ItemsSource="{Binding EndEvents, Mode=OneWay}" 
                SelectionMode="Single" 
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            />
        </PivotItem>

    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Put the XAML code here, and also the Full Exception